# Почему Proxy Nuxt не работает на heroku?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js

Повторял проект с coursehunter о создании блога на Nuxt + Laravel API.
фронт и бэк были на разных доменах.
фронт стучался к бэкэкэнду по адрес/api
Локально все работало отлично.(потому что в курсе было настроено cors для laravel)

Я залил на heroku frontend одним приложением, а backend другим.
Все ключи для laravel и nuxt прописал, все заработало. Но стала вылетать ошибка CORS.
окей
погуглив, я нашел инфу о nuxt proxy.Подключил, но теперь приложение вообще не открывается. В логах heroku следующая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать в nuxt.config.js proxy и оставить в axios просто baseurl этой ошибки нет
Вот так выглядит сейчас мой nuxt.config.js:

```
    modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'https://api-for-blog.herokuapp.com/api', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''},changeOrigin: true }
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: "login", method: "post", propertyName: "meta.token" },
          user: { url: "user", method: "get", propertyName: "data" },
          logout: { url: "logout", method: "post" },
        },
      }
    },
    watchLoggedIn: true,
    rewriteRedirects: true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

`proxy` не работает при генерации статического сайта (`npm run generate`).

Вместо `proxy: true`, используй `proxy: false` и укажи другой `baseURL`
Вот [ссылка](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#baseurl)